# XMl(RSS) to Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I would like to know, How can you convert(parse) the contents of an RSS feed url to javascript code, which updates itself via the feed url? I currently use an online parser but they do not include the rss images. It's for a feed for my website.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you do a XMLHttpRequest for the URL you can get the contents in XML form instead of text. This means it should be already parsed for you and you can use the traditional DOM methods to inspect it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I know little about what your saying. I'm not really familiar with javascript. I just used the javascript code the online parser gave me and plugged it into my website. How do I do a XMLHttpRequest, and if I do have the xml sheet, how do I use the DOM methods? Can you maybe give me a simpler solution/explanation to my question. I'd appreciate

Comment: Oh, turns out I totally misread your question. I thought you were already doing a XHR request :/ Just ignore everything I said then

Comment: Are you still able to help me though, would really appreciate